# Solr - open text field configuration

Tags: solr, lucene

I have fields holding values for full text search and when I search some word like: FCS/04/012/FSC
the result also contain documents with no value like FCS/04/012/FSC or event contains 04/012 but, contain 06 or 012 etc

Fileds configuration:

```
<fieldType name="text_pl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!--<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />-->
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!--<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>-->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<!-- A text field with defaults appropriate for English: it
     tokenizes with StandardTokenizer, removes English stop words
     (lang/stopwords_en.txt), down cases, protects words from protwords.txt, and
     finally applies Porter's stemming.  The query time analyzer
     also applies synonyms from synonyms.txt. -->
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
-->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
-->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I want only documents which are contain value:FCS/04/012/FSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a phrase query, by enclosing the search term in quotes:

```
value:"FCS/04/012/FSC"
```

See the [Lucene query parser syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview).